# WCF- pass per request information in pipelines

Tags: wcf

I have a scenario in which I need to share some per request data from WCF authentication module to actual service method. I also want this data not to be sent to client. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this: [WCF Intermediate Service between Client and Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29775/WCF-Intermediate-Service-between-Client-and-Server)